# Confused of an Example in Probabilities

Tags: probability

I see this example while studying something.

[image]

My question is:

> Why "What is the probability that a ball now drawn from the second bag is black?", when starting to show the answer,  is translated as "We are interested in the union of the mutually exclusive events $B_1 \cap B_2$ and $W_1 \cap B_2$ ?

I didn't understand at all....so I want to be enlightened......

Comment: We are asked for the probability that the ball we draw from the second bag is black.  That corresponds to the event $B_2$.  Now... remembering that a ball that we draw from the first bag must either be white or black but not both simultaneously, we know that $W_1\cup B_1=\Omega$, the entire sample space.  We know that $\Omega\cap B_2=B_2$ by properties of the sample space.  So, $B_2=B_2\cap \Omega=B_2\cap (B_1\cup W_1)=(B_2\cap B_1)\cup (B_w\cap W_1)$ and since these last two are disjoint we have $Pr(B_2)=Pr(B_2\cap B_1)+Pr(B_2\cap W_1)$.

Comment: As for the reasoning why we want to even do this in the first place, it is to make calculations easier and more natural.  We know how to find the probability of $B_2$ given a specific number of black and white balls in the second bag, but only if we know what those values actually are.  Without keeping track of what ball was moved from the first bag we don't know if there were actually $4$ white and $5$ black balls or if there were actually $3$ white and $6$ black balls in the second bag at the time of drawing.